# Why does zipWith.zipWith work?

Tags: haskell, zipwith

I am implementing a function `combine :: [[a]] -> [[b]] -> (a -> b -> c) -> [[c]]` which given two 2D lists, applies a given function `f :: a -> b -> c` to the entries of the 2D list. In other words:

```
          [[a, b, c],    [[r, s, t],          [[f a r, f b s, f c t], 
combine    [d, e, g],     [u, v, w],   f   =   [f d u, f e v, f g w],
           [h, i, j]]     [x, y, z]]           [f h x, f i y, f j z]]
```

Now I suspect that `combine = zipWith . zipWith`, because I have tried it out and it is giving me the intended results, e.g.

```
(zipWith . zipWith) (\x y -> x+y) [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] [[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
```

gives the expected result `[[8,10,12],[14,16,18]]`, but I cannot understand why this works, because I don't understand how the type of `zipWith . zipWith` turns out to be `(a -> b -> c) -> [[a]] -> [[b]] -> [[c]]`.

Is `(.)` here still carrying out the usual function composition? If so, can you explain how this applies to `zipWith`?

Comment: Actually you may also consider looking at [`Control.Applicative.ZipList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:ZipList) type for this type of operations.

Comment: BTW, you can pass the addition operator as a function: `(zipWith . zipWith) (+) [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] [[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To infer the type of an expression such as `zipWith . zipWith`, you can simulate the unification in your head the following way.

The first `zipWith` has type `(a -> b -> c) -> ([a] -> [b] -> [c])`, the second `(s -> t -> u) -> ([s] -> [t] -> [u])` and `(.)` has type `(m -> n) -> (o -> m) -> (o -> n)`.

For it to typecheck, you need:

- `m` = `(a -> b -> c)`
- `n` = `([a] -> [b] -> [c])`
- `o` = `(s -> t -> u)`
- `m` = `([s] -> [t] -> [u])` => `a` = `[s]`, `b` = `[t]`, `c` = `[u]` because of the first constraint

Then the returned type is `o -> n` which is `(s -> t -> u) -> ([a] -> [b] -> [c])` from the constraints and going one step further `(s -> t -> u) -> ([[s]] -> [[t]] -> [[u]])`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `.` is the normal function composition operator:

```
Prelude> :type (.)
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

One way to look at it is that it takes an `a` value, first calls the `a -> b` function, and then uses the return value of that function to call the `b -> c` function. The result is a `c` value.

Another way to look at `(zipWith . zipWith)`, then, is to perform an eta expansion:

```
Prelude> :type (zipWith . zipWith)
(zipWith . zipWith) :: (a -> b -> c) -> [[a]] -> [[b]] -> [[c]]

Prelude> :t (\x -> zipWith $ zipWith x)
(\x -> zipWith $ zipWith x)
  :: (a -> b -> c) -> [[a]] -> [[b]] -> [[c]]

Prelude> :t (\x -> zipWith (zipWith x))
(\x -> zipWith (zipWith x))
  :: (a -> b -> c) -> [[a]] -> [[b]] -> [[c]]
```

The type of `zipWith` itself:

```
Prelude> :type zipWith
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
```

So, in the above lambda expression, `x` must be `(a -> b -> c)`, and hence `zipWith x` must have the type `[a] -> [b] -> [c]`.

The *outer* `zipWith` also needs a function `(a1 -> b1 -> c1)`, which matches `zipWith x` if `a1` is `[a]`, `b1` is `[b]`, and `c1` is `[c]`.

So, by replacement, `zipWith (zipWith x)` must have the type `[[a]] -> [[b]] -> [[c]]`, and therefore the type of the lambda expression is `(a -> b -> c) -> [[a]] -> [[b]] -> [[c]]`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of seeing it is that lists with the zipping operation form an `Applicative`, and the [composition](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html#t:Compose) (nesting) of `Applicative`s is still `Applicative`:

```
λ import Control.Applicative
λ import Data.Functor.Compose
λ let l1 = ZipList [ZipList [1,2,3], ZipList [4,5,6]]
λ let l2 = ZipList [ZipList [7,8,9], ZipList [10,11,12]]
λ getCompose $ (+) <$> Compose l1 <*> Compose l2
ZipList {getZipList = [ZipList {getZipList = [8,10,12]},
                       ZipList {getZipList = [14,16,18]}]}
```

The `ZipList` newtype is required because "bare" lists have a different `Applicative` instance, which forms all combinations instead of zipping.

Comment: Or... `(<*>) . ((+) <$>) <$> l1 <*> l2` without `Data.Functor.Compose`.

Comment: @Redu While more compact, I find the newtype-less version more difficult to understand.

Comment: Yes i have to agree that point-free sometimes might seem confusing at first glance. Basically `(<*>) . ((+) <$>)` is ` \x y -> (+) <$> x <*> y`.